# web application vs web based application

Tags: php, security, web, web-applications

What is the diffrence between web application and web based application.

I found it in this article:

> The Web Hacking Incident Database only tracks media reported security
>   incidents that can be associated with a web application security
>   vulnerability....
>    The database does not include known vulnerabilities
>   in web based applications, an area well covered by other databases
>
> Source URL:
>   http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246992/Web-Hacking-Incident-Database-FAQ#What_incidents_are_included_in_the_Web_Hacking_Incidents_Database

Can some one help?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terminology

Comment: Who says there is a difference? Sounds like the same to me, as do first couple of search results I found

Answer (score 1):

Web Application:
A Web application (Web app) is an application program that is stored on a remote server and delivered over the Internet through a browser interface.

Web based application:
An application in which all or some parts of the software are downloaded from the Web each time it is run. It may refer to browser-based apps that run within the user's Web browser, or to "rich client" desktop apps that do not use a browser or to mobile apps that access the Web for additional information.